# php - convert hours : mins to the corresponding epoch time that the value would be today

Tags: php, time, epoch

I have 2 values that i wish to convert to the epoch equivilent that will happen today.

Currently i have;
hour - 16
minute - 30

so here i've got half 4 or 16:30 which today would be 1314804607 in epoch

The question is how do I do this conversion each day to get the epoch value of today's 16:30

thanks for your help in advance,

It's that time and im tired :P probably really easy!

Andy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since [`mktime`](https://www.php.net/mktime) defaults the values to the current date/time, we can only override the values you need:

```
$hours = 16;
$minutes = 30;

echo mktime($hours, $minutes);
```

That will always output the timestamp of `16:30` in your local timezone on the day it was ran...

Comment: ... so simple! kicking myself now :) I was doing the following strtotime(date('d-m-Y H:i:s', mktime(16, 30, 0))) *facepalm* thanks ircmaxell